# pandas groupby returns multiindex with two more aggregates

Tags: pandas, group-by

When grouping by a single column, and using as_index=False, the behavior is expected in pandas.  However, when I use `.agg`, `as_index` no longer appears to behave as expected.  In short, it doesn't appear to matter.

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# set the seed
np.random.seed(834)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 1), columns=['a'])

df['letter'] = np.random.choice(['a','b'], size=10)

summary = df.groupby('letter', as_index=False).agg([np.count_nonzero, np.mean])
summary
```

returns:

```
    a
count_nonzero   mean
letter      
a   6.0 0.539313
b   4.0 0.456702
```

When I would have expected the axis to be 0 1 with letter as a column in the dataframe.

In summary, I want to be able to group by one or more columns, summarize a single column with multiple aggregates, and return a dataframe that does not have the group by columns as the index, nor a Multi Index in the column.

Comment: `summary = df.groupby('letter')['a'].agg([np.count_nonzero, np.mean]).reset_index()`. If the agg column isn't specified, it's added as level 0 in the columns.

Comment: holy moly how did I overlook that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from @Trenton did the trick.

`summary = df.groupby('letter')['a'].agg([np.count_nonzero, np.mean]).reset_index()`